# Django CMS Project no such table: reversion_revision

Tags: python, django

I am building a relatively simple app using Django 1.9.13 and DjangoCMS, to be explicit. I get a pesky error presented below whenever I try to add a new user to the system (using Aldryn People Plugin for DjangoCMS). I also get this error when trying to add some other entities to the site.

However, this error seems more Django-related than related to particular apps I am using. Hence, I am wondering if you have any suggestion on how one could fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

The error:

> no such table: reversion_revision Request Method: POST Request
>
> URL:  http://localhost:8000/admin/aldryn_people/person/add/?language=en-us
>
> Django Version:   1.9.13 Exception Type:  OperationalError Exception
>
> Value:     no such table: reversion_revision

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for XXXXX project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'treebeard',
    'sekizai',

    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'mptt',

    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_video',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',

    'aldryn_bootstrap3',
    'aldryn_apphooks_config',
    'aldryn_categories',
    'aldryn_common',
    'aldryn_newsblog',
    'aldryn_people',
    'aldryn_reversion',
    'aldryn_translation_tools',
    'parler',
    'sortedm2m',
    'taggit',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'XXXXX.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        #'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
                'aldryn_boilerplates.context_processors.boilerplate',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                # important! place right before django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader
                'aldryn_boilerplates.template_loaders.AppDirectoriesLoader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ]
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    # important - place immediately before AppDirectoriesFinder
    'aldryn_boilerplates.staticfile_finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

CMS_TEMPLATES = [
    ('home.html', 'Home page template'),
]

THUMBNAIL_HIGH_RESOLUTION = True

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters'
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'XXXXX.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

SITE_ID = 1

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en-us', 'English'),
]

ALDRYN_BOILERPLATE_NAME = 'bootstrap3'
```

Requirements.txt

```
aldryn-apphooks-config==0.3.3
aldryn-boilerplates==0.7.5
aldryn-bootstrap3==1.2.2
aldryn-categories==1.0.4
aldryn-common==1.0.4
aldryn-newsblog==1.3.3
aldryn-people==1.2.2
aldryn-reversion==1.1.0
aldryn-translation-tools==0.2.1
Babel==2.4.0
backport-collections==0.1
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.9.13
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-appdata==0.1.6
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-cms==3.4.3
django-filer==1.2.7
django-formtools==2.0
django-mptt==0.8.7
django-parler==1.7
django-phonenumber-field==1.3.0
django-polymorphic==1.0.2
django-reversion==1.10.2
django-sekizai==0.10.0
django-sortedm2m==1.3.3
django-taggit==0.22.1
django-treebeard==4.1.0
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.7
djangocms-attributes-field==0.2.0
djangocms-column==1.7.0
djangocms-file==2.0.2
djangocms-googlemap==1.1.0
djangocms-installer==0.9.6
djangocms-link==2.1.2
djangocms-picture==2.0.5
djangocms-snippet==1.9.2
djangocms-style==2.0.2
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.5.0
djangocms-video==2.0.3
easy-thumbnails==2.3
html5lib==0.9999999
lxml==3.7.3
olefile==0.44
phonenumbers==8.4.3
phonenumberslite==8.4.3
Pillow==4.1.1
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-slugify==1.2.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
tzlocal==1.4
Unidecode==0.4.20
YURL==0.13
```

Comment: did you run migrations?

Comment: Yes. I was actually just able to fix it. An app was missing from the list of installed apps. The tutorials I followed never mentioned it.

Comment: Did you check the database if there is such a table or not?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running `pip install django-revision` and adding `revision` to the list of installed apps.